# Why is `MooseX::Traits::apply_traits()` deprecated?

Tags: perl, moose

This question is specifically about [MooseX::Traits](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aTraits). The method `apply_traits` has been deprecated and it gives a warning message as follows:

```
apply_traits is deprecated due to being fundamentally broken. 
disable this warning with "no warnings 'MooseX::Traits'"
```

Can anyone explain why it is 'fundamentally broken'? 
It passes its own tests on that method, and it works for what I'm trying to do. Is it because it uses `Moose::Meta::Role::apply()`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you what you want to know, but I would advise you to find another way of doing 
what you want to do, just to save you a lot of work further down the road.

I attempted to use it in production, and it kept causing problems with other parts of Moose until I ripped it out again. I have forgotten specifics, but ended up talking to one of the main guys behind Moose at that time, and he was unable to help.

Apparently, the situation has not improved. I would heed the warning.

Just a bit of advice, sorry I could not answer your question.